# How to insert data into access db in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is the code. problem is overwriting the table values each time when i run the code. Please give some solution

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please fill the details")
Else
    Try

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\hr.accdb;")
            conn.Open()

            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("insert into admin (uname,pwd) values (@uname, @pwd)", conn)

            With command.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@pwd", TextBox2.Text)

            End With

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Recorded!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()

            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End If
```

Comment: Does your table have a primary key like an integer that is changing with each insert? It seems like an insert should never update existing data. Is it possible the something else is clearing the table between page loads?

Comment: I checked.. but its the same again....... i searched in google..i got so many codes..there is no change with ma code... but....anybody can give solution....please advise that .what change i need to make in ma code............